# PydanticImportError: Generate dataset profile report using Pandas profiling

Tags: pandas

For generating pandas profile report,
`import pandas as pd from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport Load your dataset (replace 'your_dataset.csv' with the actual file path or URL) data = pd.read_csv('path.csv') profile = ProfileReport(data, title='Pandas Profiling Report', explorative=True) profile.to_file("pandas_profiling_report.html")`
Here with `from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`, got error:
PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package.
Installed !pip install pydantic-settings and added 'from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings' Still getting error. How to solve this?

Comment: Got it. With these versions, !pip install pandas==2.0.3 pandas-profiling==3.6.6 it works. If latest versions, need to use  `import ydata_profiling` instead 'from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport'

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP's comment, we need to select two specific package versions:

```
pip install pandas==2.0.3 pandas-profiling==3.6.6
```

It locks the version of the `pandas` and the `pandas-profiling` package.